# jquery how to construct each or for loop construction with tr:nth-child(i)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, for-loop

I have the following jQuery snippet:

```
$('.product tr:nth-child(2) .knop',window.parent.document).bind("click", function(){
    $('#edit-submitted-data-cursus').val($('.product tr:nth-child(2) .cursus a',window.parent.document).html())
    $('#edit-submitted-data-cursusdatum').val($('.product tr:nth-child(2) .datum',window.parent.document).html())
    $('#edit-submitted-data-opleidingscode').val($('.product tr:nth-child(2) .code',window.parent.document).html())
    $('#edit-submitted-data-cursuslocatie').val($('.product tr:nth-child(2) .loc',window.parent.document).html())
    $('#edit-submitted-data-cursustarief').val($('.product tr:nth-child(2) .tarief',window.parent.document).html())
}); 

$('.product tr:nth-child(3) .knop',window.parent.document).bind("click", function(){
    $('#edit-submitted-data-cursus').val($('.product tr:nth-child(3) .cursus a',window.parent.document).html())
    $('#edit-submitted-data-cursusdatum').val($('.product tr:nth-child(3) .datum',window.parent.document).html())
    $('#edit-submitted-data-opleidingscode').val($('.product tr:nth-child(3) .code',window.parent.document).html())
    $('#edit-submitted-data-cursuslocatie').val($('.product tr:nth-child(3) .loc',window.parent.document).html())
    $('#edit-submitted-data-cursustarief').val($('.product tr:nth-child(3) .tarief',window.parent.document).html())
});

$('.product tr:nth-child(4) .knop',window.parent.document).bind("click", function(){
    $('#edit-submitted-data-cursus').val($('.product tr:nth-child(4) .cursus a',window.parent.document).html())
    $('#edit-submitted-data-cursusdatum').val($('.product tr:nth-child(4) .datum',window.parent.document).html())
    $('#edit-submitted-data-opleidingscode').val($('.product tr:nth-child(4) .code',window.parent.document).html())
    $('#edit-submitted-data-cursuslocatie').val($('.product tr:nth-child(4) .loc',window.parent.document).html())
    $('#edit-submitted-data-cursustarief').val($('.product tr:nth-child(4) .tarief',window.parent.document).html())
});

    etc.
```

I have 54 functions like that. That's a lot of redundancy. So I would like to have a loop, but until now I have not been able to succeed. Shouldn't be too difficult, but it's just above my head :-(

Can somebody help me? Thanks already!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should work:

```
var productsRows = $('.product tr');
productsRows.on('click', '.knop button', function(evt){
    var currentTarget = $(evt.currentTarget);
    var currentRow = currentTarget.parents('tr');

    $('#edit-submitted-data-cursus').val(currentRow.find('.cursus').html());
    $('#edit-submitted-data-cursusdatum').val(currentRow.find('.datum').html());
    $('#edit-submitted-data-opleidingscode').val(currentRow.find('.code').html());
    $('#edit-submitted-data-cursuslocatie').val(currentRow.find('.loc').html());
    $('#edit-submitted-data-cursustarief').val(currentRow.find('.tarief').html());
});
```

Here's a fiddle: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uLh8xvt0/1/)

This should also remove the need to differentiate between the head of the table by starting at `2` (you might wanna use `<thead>` around and `<th>` instead of `<td>` for that anyways), since it just listens for clicks on buttons in the `.knop` cell (if there's no button, the event can't fire).

Comment: Thanks for helping me out, but unfortunately none of the solutions work for me. I also thought a simple for loop would do it, but it doesn't and I can't figure it out. The code works when I don't use a loop and just fill in the position of the tr:nth-child() with a number, but then of course all the values are the same for each row. Anybody else?

Comment: Did you try the second solution I proposed? Please update your post with your current code (also provide a fiddle if possible, maybe the problem lies elsewhere)

Comment: yes, I tried that too. 

I have made a simplified code sample (I'm not sure how to work with fiddle) on http://www.wideopenwindows.be/testform.html
If you look in de source code you will see the active script. This is working only for the table row for 'Access'. Of course this does not work on the other rows. The code that's commented out is a simple for loop and it doesn't work :-(. Maybe you want to have a look?

Comment: I've updated my answer with code that works for me in the fiddle I have added coming from your code. Hope this works for you.

Comment: Fantastic!!! it really works. Thank you!! 
Originally the form inputs are in a iframe. I will try now to get this to work, using your code.

Comment: Nope, with an iframe it doesn't work. I don't know how to work *window.parent.document* in the code for the button. I hope you still want to give me a solution for that. If you don't it's not a big deal, I have to rewrite the page and don't use an iframe.

Comment: Great! You should accept the answer then so that other people can find it :)

Comment: You're damn right. I couldn't find how to accept, but now I know :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 54; i++) {
    $('.product tr:nth-child(' + i + ') .knop',window.parent.document).bind("click", function() {
        $('#edit-submitted-data-cursus').val($('.product tr:nth-child(' + i + ') .cursus a', window.parent.document).html());
        $('#edit-submitted-data-cursusdatum').val($('.product tr:nth-child(' + i + ') .datum', window.parent.document).html());
        $('#edit-submitted-data-opleidingscode').val($('.product tr:nth-child(' + i + ') .code', window.parent.document).html());
        $('#edit-submitted-data-cursuslocatie').val($('.product tr:nth-child(' + i + ') .loc', window.parent.document).html());
        $('#edit-submitted-data-cursustarief').val($('.product tr:nth-child(' + i + ') .tarief', window.parent.document).html());
    });
}
```

Comment: this will not work since you're starting at `nth-child(0)` and ending at `nth-child(53)`

Comment: @mvuajua: PO can change borders, the important is how to make a loop in this case.